# iOS Swift how to get an image capture on hls(http live stream)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, cgimageref

How to get image capture on hls(http live stream) with Swift on iOS?

return nil at "capturedImage" on below code.

```
func onCaptureButtonClick(sender : UIButton){

    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: avAsset)
    generator.maximumSize = self.videolayer.frame.size

    let   time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);

    let capturedImage : CGImageRef! = generator.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil, error: nil)

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,self.view.bounds.height/2, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height / 2))
    imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: capturedImage)

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

}
```

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm after the same requirement but cant get it working.